# Match everything but not part of a url

Tags: regex, url, regex-negation

I'm trying to make a regex to match any ending except `ClaroArgentina`
So, this should not match: `https://twitter.com/#!/ClaroArgentina`
But this should be a match: `https://twitter.com/#!/asdasd`

Im trying to make it work with this, but its not giving me results:

```
https\://twitter\.com/(^ClaroArgentina)
```

What im trying to archieve in that regex is to match on everything but not ClaroArgentina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in most languages.

```
http\://twitter\.com/#!/(?!ClaroArgentina)$
```

Comment: Its matching for `https://twitter.com/#!/asdasd` and for `https://twitter.com/#!/ClaroArgentina`, when It should not match for the last one.

Comment: `https\://twitter\.com/#!/(?!ClaroArgentina)$` is not matching for any. Im using this tool to test the matches: `http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html`

Comment: I missed the `#!`. try again. with `https\://twitter\.com/#!/(?!ClaroArgentina).*$`

Comment: `https\://twitter\.com/#!/(?!ClaroArgentina).*$` gives me syntax errors :S

Comment: `https\://twitter\.com/#!/(?!ClaroArgentina).*` works in regexpal  Make sure you are escaping it correctly.  What flavor are you using?

Comment: `https://twitter\.com/#!/(?!ClaroArgentina).*$` the first escaping on `https` was not required. Thanks

Comment: Why are you escaping the colon?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to accept the answer. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use just the RegEx?  The simplest way would be to use String.EndsWith.